# GROUP_CONCAT DISTINCT ， DISTINCT not work

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT
    GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT unit.`name` ORDER BY unit.`order_index` ASC SEPARATOR '/' ) AS nameGroup 
FROM
    pms_spec_unit unit
    JOIN pms_spec spec ON spec.id = unit.spec_id 
WHERE
    spec.`status` = 1 
GROUP BY
    unit.spec_id 
HAVING
    nameGroup LIKE '%年%'
```

---

duplicate result

[The results I got](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I3FbC.png)

mysql version 8.0.25

Comment: What happen if you add `unit.spec_id` in `SELECT`? Like  `SELECT unit.spec_id, GROUP_CONCAT( ..... )`? By the way, please improve your question formatting. Image posting is encouraged when only you can't describe something in textual form. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Thanks

Comment: These are equal values obtained for different `unit.spec_id`. Use ```SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(unit.`NAME`...```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score -1):

I solved this issue thanks to [Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina)'s [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69081864/group-concat-distinct-distinct-not-work/69097891#comment122095708_69081864). Actually `unit.spec_id` is different. Use `SELECT DISTINCT GROUP_CONCAT(...`.

Comment: @SorousHBakhtiary I think the opening of *"I solved this issue"* actually show that this is indeed an answer...